# Angularjs expandable table row

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, angularjs-ng-click, angular-datatables

I am using angular 1.4.3 and angular dataTables (here's the link: http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables).

My needs is basic. I need to expand the row when it is clicked and all the `ng-click`'s or the others need to work. But in the docs of library they fires the callback like this;

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

when I try to add a button that has `ng-click` to that format function in the example. It doesn't work (I mean `ng-click` does not work.). I think the problem accurs because of the element appends to table after the document load.

Do you habve any idea about it?

Comment: can you post a plunker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `ng-click` has to be `$compile`'d before it is any good. But you do not *have* to go all the angular way : Since dataTables is a jQuery plugin you can still use delegated event handlers and so on - the biggest problem is to access the API, fortunetaly we can use the `dtInstance` instead. Here is a angular-datatables version of the infamous Child rows example :

Markup :

```html
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstance"></table>
```

Basic initialisation, use a remote JSON source (notice `.details-control` is set here):

```js
$scope.dtColumns = [
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('Name')
                                   .withOption('className', 'details-control'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('position').withTitle('Position'),
  DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('salary').withTitle('salary')
];  

$scope.dtInstance = {};

$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
  .fromSource('https://api.myjson.com/bins/2v7sr')
  .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
  .withDataProp('data');
```

"Child rows" example ported so it works in angular :

```js
var format = function ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
           '<td>Full name:</td>'+
           '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
           '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
           '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
           '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
           '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
         '</tr>'+
        '</table>';
}

$('body').on('click', '.details-control', function() {
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   var row = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row( tr );
   if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
   } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
   }
})
```

Basically it is the same, just listening on `body` as parent element for the delegation, using `dtInstance` instead of a dataTable API instance.

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/0CA9jMIg4gXqj9fnY38p?p=preview**

Comment: How would this work? We're adding jQuery selectors to an Angular page--wouldn't this require a directive?

Comment: Its nice but once i have click on child row then after parent row click not working.  any idea about that @davidkonrad

Comment: @MayankVadiya, Thank you for pointing me to this old question! The plunkr was broken so have updated it. Perhaps it helps to see it in action, cannot replicate what you describe above (perhaps you are doing something different)

Comment: I want to open modal in child row button @davidkonrad

Comment: @MayankVadiya, well - you must either `$compile` the child content or open the modal using jQuery / vanilla.